# Javascript - Split string by white space and join two words by "|"

Tags: javascript, extendscript

I think this is very easy but I can't figure it out.

```
var str = "How are you doing today?";
var res = str.split(/\s+/g);
```

And the result would be: `How,are,you,doing,today?`. When user add character "|" between two words like this

```
var str = "How are you |doing today?";
```

The result shoul be: `How,are,you doing,today?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First replace all white spaces with a pipe. Then replace by a white space each time you encounter two or more pipes. Then split by pipe :

```js
var str = `How  are you |doing today?
fine | thanx`;
var arr = str.replace(/ {1,}/g,"|").replace(/\|{2,}/g," ").split(/\||\n/);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: But it join the new line too. The last word in the first row is joined to the first word in the second row. Could it be fixed?

Comment: This would also group words if there are 2 consecutive spaces in the input string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var source = "How are you |doing today?";
var result = source
  .split(/\s+(?!\|)/g)
  .map(function(segment) {
    return segment.replace(/((\s+)\|)/g, '$2');
  });
  
console.log(result);
```

First the string is `split` onto whitespace sequences that *are not followed* by a pipe character (`|`) using a *negative lookahead*, then the resulting array is mapped such as that for each segment whitespace sequences followed by a pipe character are replaced with only the whitespace part (`$2`) of each matching group (`$1`).

---

In case that `Array.map` is not implemented in Extendscript, here's another example using a regular `for` loop:

```js
var source = "How are you |doing today?";
var rawArray = source.split(/\s+(?!\|)/g);
var result = [];

for (var i = 0; i < rawArray.length; i++) {
  result[i] = rawArray[i].replace(/((\s+)\|)/g, '$2');
}
  
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Hi Jeffrey, arrow function doesn't work in extendscript. Is there any other way to do this. Thanks

Comment: @A I already replaced ES2015 features with ES5 earlier. Does it still not work? Maybe `Array.map` is not implemented in Extendscript? I have updated my answer with an additional example.

Comment: I've just found that (Array.reduce(), Array.forEach(), Array.map(), etc...). doesn't work in extednscript.

Comment: Please try the second snippet in my answer, using a `for` loop and intermediate variable as a substitute to `Array.map`.

Comment: Now it's working but it delete "doing". The result is: "How are you  today?"

Answer (score 0):

You can't do what you describe *just* `split`. You could get close using a negative lookahead assertion (`/ (?!\|)/`), but it leaves the `|` in the string:

```js
var str = "How are you |doing today?";
var arr = str.split(/ (?!\|)/);
console.log(arr);
```

...so we have to do more. Probably the simplest thing is to replace the space-plus-bar with a space after the split:

```js
var str = "How are you |doing today?";
var arr = str.split(/ (?!\|)/).map(function(s) {
  return s.replace(/ \|/g, ' ');
});
console.log(arr);
```

or in ES2015+:

```js
const str = "How are you |doing today?";
const arr = str.split(/ (?!\|)/).map(s => s.replace(/ \|/g, ' '));
console.log(arr);
```